# Is there any way to improve performance on like searches that have the % to the left of the searched value?

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, string-searching

I have a query that does a like statement on a column that stores fullpath locations of files on a computer.

Example

```
select * 
from table 
where fullpath like '%hi.exe'
```

Which never seems to use an index and is very slow compared to doing a fullpath = 'value' (obviously)

But my question is, is there any way or ideas on how to speed up query results or get it to use indexes?

I dont see the same slowness if the like is on the right side (ex select * from table where fullpath like 'hi%'

EDIT: Microsoft Sql server 2017 Standard Edition

Comment: In some databases there's an index type that will help with this (e.g. postgres trigram index.) I don't know whether sql server has anything like that.

Comment: @GlennWillen Unfortunately SQL Server does not natively, but it is possible to write your own code to mimic how trigrams work. But it's not necessarily a simple thing to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

FWIW, I don't think the previously provided *duplicate* questions were actually duplicate of this specific question and instead answered a more complex tangentially related question on how to improve searching with double wildcards (*contains* type of searches). Some of the answers probably can be applied here as well, but are overly complicated for this much easier problem, hence my vote to re-open the question. I tried locating a suitable duplicate with the simpler solution but could not find one.

---

> Is there any way to improve performance on like searches that have the % to the left of the searched value?

Assuming you do strictly mean only *starts-with* type of searches (only leading wildcards) and not *contains* type of searches, then there are some fairly simple solutions.

One solution involves storing a copy of the column reversed (a computed column can help here) and then creating an index on the reversed column. Then you can reverse your wildcard order to make it an *ends-with* search against the reversed column. This would be logically equivalent and also be [sargable](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable), therefore allowing the index to be used in an efficient manner.

Example code:

```
-- Step 1: Add a computed column with the reversed column
ALTER TABLE YourTable
ADD fullpath_reversed AS REVERSE(fullpath);

-- Step 2: Index the newly created reversed column 
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_YourTable_fullpath_reversed ON YourTable (fullpath_reversed);

-- Step 3: Query the newly created column efficiently 
select * 
from YourTable 
where fullpath_reversed like 'exe.ih%';
```

---

Note you shouldn't use `SELECT *` in any non-adhoc code, especially when you're concerned about performance. Only list out the columns you actually care about for that particular query. It's more performant both from reading less data than necessary and potentially resulting in a better query plan, with indexes chosen, and index operations used.

Comment: I've seen the same answer online else where too so I'll have to take it into consideration and try it. Thanks for the info though and reiterating that as a solution that could work.

Comment: To slightly modify what you said, you have to make the computed column "PERSISTED" if you want to build an index on it. Also not sure yet how this behaves with bulk inserts into the table. While not using a persisted will instead make it like a view where the table is calculated at the time of doing selects which could cause slowness and also again cant be used within an index.

Change below

Comment: -- Step 1: Add a computed column with the reversed column

ALTER TABLE YourTable

ADD fullpath_reversed AS REVERSE(fullpath) PERSISTED;


-- Step 2: Index the newly created reversed column 

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_YourTable_fullpath_reversed ON YourTable 

(fullpath_reversed);


-- Step 3: Query the newly created column efficiently 

select * 

from YourTable 

where fullpath_reversed like 'exe.ih%';

Comment: @stevenmock That's not true. An index can be created on a non-persisted computed column. See [this dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/bnCKuq7P) for an example.

Comment: If for some reason you wanted to persist it anyway, bulk inserts would likely be fine for such a trivial expression unless you're inserting hundreds of millions of rows at a time in a single insert statement.

Comment: I'll have to take a look, I was just going off of microsoft's documentation itself but would be interesting if that wasn't the case based on what I read about computed columns. If they aren't persisted then the values aren't physically stored and only generated at the time of selects so I would assume that means no index can be built on it. 

The non persisted value not actually existing until you run a select seems to be true because you can create a computed column in 0 seconds but took an hour to create a computed persisted column.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/indexes-on-computed-columns?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks again for your help btw.

Comment: @StevenM No problem! So yea the docs you linked state the requirements and `PERSISTED` is not one of them. The only case when it would be is "*Any computed column that contains a common language runtime (CLR) expression*". A CLR expression is a custom C# written function that one can deploy to their SQL Server, but that's different than the native functions built into SQL Server (like the `REVERSE()`) function.

Comment: When you persist the column and index it, the data is being stored in two places, in the table itself and in the index (which is a copy of the data). By not persisting it, only the index stores a copy of the data but the table itself will calculate it at runtime. So by not persisting the computed column, there's a little less write overhead when the table is written to.

Answer (score 6):

If you typically search for file names, store them separately instead of embedded in `fullpath`.

Might be better to store path, file name, and maybe extension separately depending on the queries.

Will use less space than a reversed copy of the `fullpath`.

Comment: I was going to write same thing. Usually this  the practice

Comment: This is for sure a good solution as well. And I mentioned as such to the developers and bosses. But that code change is more so on their end and not something I can control.

Answer (score 1):

Maintain a separate column with less width for filename only.Also if you multiple file extension type then you can maintain tinyint flag in separate column.

It is only one time task during insert/update proc.

This way you can avoid `Like` operator altogether.

`SARGable` is only one of the factor for optimizer for using Index

Another main factor is column width.Less the column width,there will be less number of index page.So optimizer will have to read less page,so more the chance of using Index.

Optimizer often make good enough plan and cost effective plan.In some case even if Index is not use but still plan is good enough.

Do not make Index on column of datatype varchar with more width.If table contain million of rows later then this index get wasted and might take longer to execute even small query which return less number of rows